# Percentages and Viewport height/width aren't adjusting proportions in relations to formatted text

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a project, and I want the text to be centered, and stay proportional to eachother when resized. When I changed the method of keeping it in the center without having the div span across the whole screen it appears to change the proportions of where the text is located on the screen.

I was previously using percentages for the three div id's == the three text lines. The code  looks like the following:

```
`#moot3{

  color: white;

  font-family: LemonMilk;
  text-shadow: 11px 10px 20px black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 52.25%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) ;
user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none; 
-ms-user-select: none; `
```

On a 1920x1080 Monitor it looked perfect, with each css block differentiating in the percentages where appropriate.
https://gyazo.com/f7435bc684648e624e114c010b6ea61d

However on a 1366x768 monitor and mobile it looked the same, which is overlapped.
https://gyazo.com/2b272f52e3a18db6cb66290a4e8d427e

I have tried exchanging the percentages for 'vw, and vh' in hopes for it to take the value times the viewport size, but to no avail it looks the same.
The Changed Code:

```
`#moot2{

  color: white;
  font-family: LemonMilkIt;
  text-shadow: 11px 10px 20px black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 56.5vh;
  left: 50vw;
  margin-right: -50vw;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  user-select: none;
}`
```

I am currently at a loss of what to do next, some help would be appreciated :smiley:

Full HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Vuelvo | Coming Soon</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="icon.png">
</head>
<body>


<!-- particles.js container -->
<div id="moot"><font size="+7">Vuelvo</font></div>
<div id="moot2"><font size="+3">Coming Soon</font></div>
<div id="moot3"><font size="+3">_________________</font></div>
<div id="particles-js"></div>

<!-- scripts -->
<script src="js/particles.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>








</body>
</html>
```

Full CSS:

```
html,body{ 
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#111;
}

html{
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

body{
  font:normal 75% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

canvas{
  display:block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}


@font-face {
  font-family: LemonMilk;
  src: url(LemonMilk.otf);
}
@font-face {
  font-family: LemonMilkIt;
  src: url(LemonMilkitalic.otf);
}

/* ---- particles.js container ---- */

#particles-js{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #343434;
  background-image: url('');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 11px 10px 20px black;
  font-family: LemonMilk;
  text-align: center; text-align: center;

}

#moot{

  color: white;
  font-family: LemonMilk;
  text-shadow: 11px 10px 20px black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none; 
  -ms-user-select: none; 
}

#moot2{

  color: white;
  font-family: LemonMilkIt;
  text-shadow: 11px 10px 20px black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 56.5%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none; 
  -ms-user-select: none; 
}

#moot3{

  color: white;

  font-family: LemonMilk;
  text-shadow: 11px 10px 20px black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 52.25%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) ;
user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none; 
-ms-user-select: none; 
}
@viewport {
  width: device-width ;
  zoom: 1.0 ;
}
```

Comment: Could you please share your html as well.

Comment: Code has been updated with full css/html

Comment: I run the code in my editor and on webpage I can just see the vuelvo coming soon nothing else. It would be better if you can share on the jsfiddle so we can see a working copy.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/folder/kwbhyxsixrnwc/Vuelvo